# Access website from domain before DNS update

Tags: dns, hosting, hosts

How I can access the temporary URL the host provided (such `http://server9.company.com/~myname` as my domain or any other domain without tralling slash before DNS update?

**For example:** Access http://server9.company.com/~myname as http://www.example.com

- I do not have a dedicated IP

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a Windows OS then you can update your `hosts` file to include the desired name and the IP address of your shared hosting box.

In Windows 7 the file is located at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` There should be a couple of examples in the file but you basically want to add;

`<ip of hosting server>        www.example.com`

If you are using a different OS please let me know so I can update the answer.

Comment: I tried it but it does not refer me to `http://server9.company.com/~myname`, it does only to `http://server9.company.com` and I still need to add `/~myname` in the URL to access it ...

Comment: Sorry I miss read; there is no way to redirect to the ~myname part unless you can run a local webserver/redirector. By adding the stuff to the hosts file that gets you round accessing the shared server so it returns the correct website when run as a vhost. I will remove this (incorrect answer)